# create parameters in parameters.ini in Symfony2 and access in all Twig Files

Tags: symfony, twig

How to create Constant in Symfony2 from a variable defined in `parameters.ini` so I can use that constant in all twig Files.

Example:

**parameters.ini:**

```
blog="https://www.blog.com"
```

Constant value declaration where I have to declare so that it accessible in all twig files.?

```
'blog_link' => $this->container->getParameter( 'blog' )
```

**view:**

```
<a href="{{blog_link}}" target="_blank">BLOG</a>
```

Comment: Can i able to write symphony function in config.yml i want to call parameters.ini file variable . Example : 'blog_link' => $this->container->getParameter( 'blog' );

Comment: Please check my answer. ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Problem resolved.

Comment: What is `parameters.ini`? Is it a file from Symfony2?

Comment: @A.L Yes it is a config file. Where we define parameters[Globally accessible ]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply add Twig global variable like this:

```
#app/config/config.yml
twig:
    globals:
        blog_link: '%blog%'
```

Where `%blog%` is a parameter defined earlier in `parameters.ini` just like you've already did.

More info in [Symfony's Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html)

Comment: Hi @MohammadFareed if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/237701) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thanks @Dragoste. i am not aware of this feature.

Comment: Can i access the blog_link in js File.?

Comment: Only if it is a Twig template. A workaround could be to create a global variable in JS code in Twig template and then use it (the JS variable) anywhere you want in JS files, but that looks a bit like a dirty hack to me ;-)